# Mocking TypeORM with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, typeorm

How can I mock TypeORM's repository methods with Jest?

For example, I have:

```
someRepository.createQueryBuilder().select().getManyAndCount()
```

How can I mock this? Do I need to mock every method until the last one? But this way looks like a bad one because the sequence of methods could be different in different queries and I'll need to mock return object with all methods for every method.

And also, for example, if answer will be that I need to mock every method one by one, how can I do it from testing file? Even if I mocked `someRepository.createQueryBuilder()` to return `{ select: () => console.log('hi') }`, I won't be able to access this `select` method in test file through `someRepository.createQueryBuilder().select()`.

What should I do?

Comment: You don't. That's a complex API that you don't own. Encapsulate these methods behind an interface you _do_ own, so you can mock that as needed, and test that the queries are correct at the _integration_ level.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks! could you please send some link or something else, where can I find such examples?